# Can I define a variable name dependent on an iteration?

Tags: python, variables, iteration

```
point_list = []  
for n in field[0]:  
    point_list.append([])  
    for m in field[1]:  
        Point = FieldPoint(n, m)
```

Can I create the variable name also in dependency of m and n?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary to store key/value pairs, if that's what you want:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for n in range(10):
...     for m in range(11):
...             key = (n, m)  # creates tuple
...             value = 'foobar'
...             my_dict[key] = value
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want variably-named variables, then you want a dict or a list instead.  Rather than having a new variable at each iteration, you create one dict, and then a new key/value pair at each iteration.